# What function created this graph and output?

Tags: graphing-functions

I have a series of inputs and outputs from a function. Inputs are -100 to +100, with the middle value as 0.

The graph generated is quite distinctive:

[image]

But I cannot work out what mathematical pattern it seems to represent. This is the raw data as [input, output] :
$$\begin{array}{r|r}
-100 & 4 \\
-99 & 1 \\
-98 & 2 \\
-97 & 1 \\
-96 & 32 \\
-95 & 1 \\
-94 & 2 \\
-93 & 1 \\
-92 & 4 \\
-91 & 1 \\
-90 & 2 \\
-89 & 1 \\
-88 & 8 \\
-87 & 1 \\
-86 & 2 \\
-85 & 1 \\
-84 & 4 \\
-83 & 1 \\
-82 & 2 \\
-81 & 1 \\
-80 & 16 \\
-79 & 1 \\
-78 & 2 \\
-77 & 1 \\
-76 & 4 \\
-75 & 1 \\
-74 & 2 \\
-73 & 1 \\
-72 & 8 \\
-71 & 1 \\
-70 & 2 \\
-69 & 1 \\
-68 & 4 \\
-67 & 1 \\
-66 & 2 \\
-65 & 1 \\
-64 & 64 \\
-63 & 1 \\
-62 & 2 \\
-61 & 1 \\
-60 & 4 \\
-59 & 1 \\
-58 & 2 \\
-57 & 1 \\
-56 & 8 \\
-55 & 1 \\
-54 & 2 \\
-53 & 1 \\
-52 & 4 \\
-51 & 1 \\
-50 & 2 \\
-49 & 1 \\
-48 & 16 \\
-47 & 1 \\
-46 & 2 \\
-45 & 1 \\
-44 & 4 \\
-43 & 1 \\
-42 & 2 \\
-41 & 1 \\
-40 & 8 \\
-39 & 1 \\
-38 & 2 \\
-37 & 1 \\
-36 & 4 \\
-35 & 1 \\
-34 & 2 \\
-33 & 1 \\
-32 & 32 \\
-31 & 1 \\
-30 & 2 \\
-29 & 1 \\
-28 & 4 \\
-27 & 1 \\
-26 & 2 \\
-25 & 1 \\
-24 & 8 \\
-23 & 1 \\
-22 & 2 \\
-21 & 1 \\
-20 & 4 \\
-19 & 1 \\
-18 & 2 \\
-17 & 1 \\
-16 & 16 \\
-15 & 1 \\
-14 & 2 \\
-13 & 1 \\
-12 & 4 \\
-11 & 1 \\
-10 & 2 \\
-9 & 1\\
-8 & 8\\
-7 & 1\\
-6 & 2\\
-5 & 1\\
-4 & 4\\
-3 & 1\\
-2 & 2\\
-1 & 1\\
0 & 0\\
1 & 1\\
2 & 2\\
3 & 1\\
4 & 4\\
5 & 1\\
6 & 2\\
7 & 1\\
8 & 8\\
9 & 1\\
10 & 2\\
11 & 1\\
12 & 4\\
13 & 1\\
14 & 2\\
15 & 1\\
16 & 16\\
17 & 1\\
18 & 2\\
19 & 1\\
20 & 4\\
21 & 1\\
22 & 2\\
23 & 1\\
24 & 8\\
25 & 1\\
26 & 2\\
27 & 1\\
28 & 4\\
29 & 1\\
30 & 2\\
31 & 1\\
32 & 32\\
33 & 1\\
34 & 2\\
35 & 1\\
36 & 4\\
37 & 1\\
38 & 2\\
39 & 1\\
40 & 8\\
41 & 1\\
42 & 2\\
43 & 1\\
44 & 4\\
45 & 1\\
46 & 2\\
47 & 1\\
48 & 16\\
49 & 1\\
50 & 2\\
51 & 1\\
52 & 4\\
53 & 1\\
54 & 2\\
55 & 1\\
56 & 8\\
57 & 1\\
58 & 2\\
59 & 1\\
60 & 4\\
61 & 1\\
62 & 2\\
63 & 1\\
64 & 64\\
65 & 1\\
66 & 2\\
67 & 1\\
68 & 4\\
69 & 1\\
70 & 2\\
71 & 1\\
72 & 8\\
73 & 1\\
74 & 2\\
75 & 1\\
76 & 4\\
77 & 1\\
78 & 2\\
79 & 1\\
80 & 16\\
81 & 1\\
82 & 2\\
83 & 1\\
84 & 4\\
85 & 1\\
86 & 2\\
87 & 1\\
88 & 8\\
89 & 1\\
90 & 2\\
91 & 1\\
92 & 4\\
93 & 1\\
94 & 2\\
95 & 1\\
96 & 32\\
97 & 1\\
98 & 2\\
99 & 1\\
100 & 4
\end{array}
$$

Comment: You do know that there are infinitely many functions that would output these exact values, right?

Comment: Yes. I suppose my questions is 'what mathematical pattern does this graph represent?', not the actual equation that produced it. Should I change the question?

Comment: You know that whenever you are given a finite amount of values, there are infinitely many patterns that produce your given values?

Comment: It looks like the Fourier transform of a signal.

Comment: This is simply the largest power of $2$ dividing the input.

Comment: When you say 'the largest power of 2' can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that powers of $2$ are $1,2,4,8,16,32,64,...$

This function is the largest power of $2$ dividing $n$.

For example,

$f(24)=8$ because $24$ is divisible by $8$ and is not divisble by $16$.